# Converting numbers to text, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, switch-statement

For an input number say 232, I wanted to be able to write out the number in text form: two hundred thirty two. I have an array which holds these numbers

```
Array[0] = 2, Array[1] = 3, Array[2] = 2.
```

I have written a

```
switch statement
```

which sees the number and prints it text, example two hundred three two. I don't know how transform that "three" into "thirty" dynamically. Suppose I have more numbers to spell, like 452,232.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't handle digits independently, it's that simple.

For example, the text for `21` is the concatenation of "twenty" and "one", but the text for `11` is not the concatenation of "ten" and "one".

Also, "1001" doesn't become "one thousand zero hundred zero one".

You can use function calls to keep logic complexity down, but you're going to need logic to look at multiple digits at once.

Comment: I think you only really need to do that for numbers 10-19 and only for certain positions (multiples of 3 counting from the least significant digit).

ie 12093 is twelve thousand ninety-three but 23093 is twenty-three thousand ninety-three and 120093 is one hundred twenty thousand ninety-three.

Comment: @Andrei: Yes, there definitely are patterns and reused rules.  Hence the suggestion to use function calls for those.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this implementation over at wikipedia](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Number_names#C.2B.2B). It is probably what you want

Copied directly from wikipedia, should the link become broken.
**Do see the link first, if an improved solution would be written**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::string;

const char* smallNumbers[] = {
  "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
  "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
  "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
  "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"
};

string spellHundreds(unsigned n) {
  string res;
  if (n > 99) {
    res = smallNumbers[n/100];
    res += " hundred";
    n %= 100;
    if (n) res += " and ";
  }
  if (n >= 20) {
    static const char* Decades[] = {
      "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",
      "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"
    };
    res += Decades[n/10];
    n %= 10;
    if (n) res += "-";
  }
  if (n < 20 && n > 0)
    res += smallNumbers[n];
  return res;
}


const char* thousandPowers[] = {
  " billion", " million",  " thousand", "" };

typedef unsigned long Spellable;

string spell(Spellable n) {
  if (n < 20) return smallNumbers[n];
  string res;
  const char** pScaleName = thousandPowers;
  Spellable scaleFactor = 1000000000;   // 1 billion
  while (scaleFactor > 0) {
    if (n >= scaleFactor) {
      Spellable h = n / scaleFactor;
      res += spellHundreds(h) + *pScaleName;
      n %= scaleFactor;
      if (n) res += ", ";
    }
    scaleFactor /= 1000;
    ++pScaleName;
  }
  return res;
}

int main() {
#define SPELL_IT(x) std::cout << #x " " << spell(x) << std::endl;
  SPELL_IT(      99);
  SPELL_IT(     300);
  SPELL_IT(     310);
  SPELL_IT(    1501);
  SPELL_IT(   12609);
  SPELL_IT(  512609);
  SPELL_IT(43112609);
  SPELL_IT(1234567890);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BenVoigt that's unfortunate.. Is there some way I can clarify that the code here is not mine, but directly copied from the link? I could as easily remove it and only provide the link, but that would be a link-only answer and I'm not very fond of that.

Comment: I think that is plenty clear.  I just wanted to comment and let readers know that the code isn't library-quality.

Answer (score 1):

Well consider the position of the number

In your case

if 3 is in position 1:  `Array[1]=3  then cout "thirty"`

if 3 is in position 2:  `Array[2]=3  then cout "three hundred"`

and so on, consider non standard cases like eleven or one hundred and one and so forth.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish");
int ikibsm, yuzler, sayi,birler,onlar;
clrscr();
do {

printf("\nSayıyı giriniz:");
scanf("%d", &sayi);

yuzler=sayi/100;
ikibsm=sayi%100;
onlar=ikibsm/10;
birler=ikibsm%10;

switch (yuzler)
{
    case 0: printf("") ;break;
    case 1: printf("Yüz ") ;break;
    case 2: printf("İkiyüz ") ;break;
    case 3: printf("Üçyüz ") ;break;
    case 4: printf("Dört Yüz ") ;break;
    case 5: printf("Beş Yüz ") ;break;
    case 6: printf("Altı Yüz ") ;break;
    case 7: printf("Yedi Yüz ") ;break;
    case 8: printf("Sekiz Yüz ") ;break;
    case 9: printf("Dokuz Yüz ") ;break;
}


 switch (onlar)
{
    case 1: printf("On ") ;break;
    case 2: printf("Yirmi ") ;break;
    case 3: printf("Otuz ") ;break;
    case 4: printf("Kırk ") ;break;
    case 5: printf("Elli ") ;break;
    case 6: printf("Altmış ") ;break;
    case 7: printf("Yetmiş ") ;break;
    case 8: printf("Seksen ") ;break;
    case 9: printf("Doksan ") ;break;
}

switch(birler)
{
    case 1: printf("Bir ") ;break;
    case 2: printf("İki ") ;break;
    case 3: printf("Üç ") ;break;
    case 4: printf("Dört ") ;break;
    case 5: printf("Beş ") ;break;
    case 6: printf("Altı ") ;break;
    case 7: printf("Yedi ") ;break;
    case 8: printf("Sekiz ") ;break;
    case 9: printf("Dokuz ") ;break;
}
} while (sayi<1000);
}
```